# Manually compile email through actionmailer & premailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm having a hard time finding documentation on how to manually compile an email using the actionmailer rails module. I'm looking for something like `content = Rails::ActionMailer.compile(raw_content)` that would do all the compilation that would normally happen on #deliver (premailer to inline styles, helper loaded content & a couple other custom functions).

I saw some documentation for using actionmailer's test methods to throw the email into a delivered array without delivering them. Is this the only thing available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Rails 4.x, you need to call `deliver` explicitly to deliver an email.

```
UserMailer.whatever("args").deliver
```

Therefore you can use (note no deliver) to get the message without sending it:

```
message = UserMailer.whatever("args")
```

If you call `#body` on message you get the content of the body.

```
message.body
```

`message` is an `ActionMailer::MessageDelivery` object which is just a wrapper around a [`Mail::Message`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mikel/mail/Mail/Message).

Comment: I'm getting a `undefined method 'send_digest' for ContentMailer:Class`. Is there any extra config I have to do to access the message without `#deliver`?

Comment: Ugh! I messed up the names during my refactor. Looks like it works!